Step Function Task for Creating Object in S3 via Multi-Region Access Point Fails with S3.SdkClientException
I'm using AWS Step Functions and I want to create an empty object in an S3 bucket located in a different account and region. I understand that I need to use a Multi-Region Access Point for this. Here is the Task definition I'm using:
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:putObject",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 5,
  "Parameters": {
    "Bucket.$": "$.DestinationBucket",
    "Key": "my-file",
    "Body": {},
    "ContentLength": 0
  },
  "End": true
}

When DestinationBucket is a Multi-Region Access Point, I encounter the following error:
{
  "error": "S3.SdkClientException",
  "cause": "Unable to execute HTTP request: null"
}

However, when DestinationBucket is a regular S3 bucket name, the task executes successfully. I have verified that the necessary permissions are in place for the Step Function to perform the operation.
Question:
What could be causing this error when using a Multi-Region Access Point, and how can I resolve it?
